# A question about Hausdorff measure

Tags: geometric-measure-theory

Let $ \mathscr{H}^m $ be the m-dimensional Hausdorff measure in $ R^n $. Let $ m<k $ and $ A \subset R^n $. If $ \mathscr{H}^m(A) < \infty $ then $ \mathscr{H}^k (A) =0 $. How can i prove this fact?

Thank you

Comment: Isn't that a fairly straightforward argument directly based on the definition of outer Hausdorff measure? Basically, $\varepsilon^k=\varepsilon^{k-m}\cdot\varepsilon^m$, and take sums … Even more accurately, if $d<\varepsilon$ then $d^k<\varepsilon^{m-k}\cdot d^m$.

Comment: Yes, after a little reflection i've seen that the proof follows immediately from the definition, as you have suggested. Thanks